# Swing JDialog slow when running remotely

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, x11, jdialog

I have experienced performance problems for JDialogs while running my GUI remotely over X11. Does anyone know a workaround?

The GUI is fast when I run it on my local machine, but sometimes we need to run it on a remote server, which causes a significant lag until the dialog is displayed. It takes about 2 seconds to create and display them.

The problem only seems to apply for modal JDialogs (including JOptionPanes).

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem with a look and feel that applied a textured image to the background of my windows.  It ran fine on the gui designer's box, but when we tried it on a LTSP X-terminal, it was dog slow.  We changed to an untextured look and feel, and things got much better.